# Books about matroids

Tags: reference-request, matroids

Could you recommend any approachable books/papers/texts about matroids (maybe a chapter from somewhere)? The ideal reference would contain multiple examples, present some intuitions and keep formalism to a necessary minimum.

I would appreciate any hints or appropriate sources.

Answer (score 9):

Dover has released a cheap version of Welsh's [Matroid Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486474399) - can't argue with the price. On the other hand, I've heard better things about Oxley's [Matroid Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199603391).

(Apparently there is absolutely no creativity in naming books on Matroid Theory)

Answer (score 6):

There is a great introduction to matroids that is about 40 pages, free, and sounds more like what  you are looking for: *What is a matroid?* by James Oxley, [available from the author's webpage](https://www.math.lsu.edu/~oxley/survey4.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

You could have a look at the relatively new book

Gary Gordon, Jennifer McNulty: *Matroids. A Geometric Introduction*, Cambridge University Press 2012.

From the description: "This book provides the first comprehensive introduction to the field which will appeal to undergraduate students and to any mathematician interested in the geometric approach to matroids. Written in a friendly, fun-to-read style and developed from the authors' own undergraduate courses, the book is ideal for students."

Answer (score 1):

I have read chapter 1 of Gordon and
McNultey's book and think it provides an
Excellent clear intro. It will get you to first
Base quickly.